# Control record navigation on MDI child form from MDI parent form

Tags: c#, datagridview, bindingnavigator

I have Form A (MDI parent) that has a `BindingNavigator` control. Using this `BindingNavigator` I would like it to navigate the records of a `DataGridView` on Form B (MDI Child).

So far on the load event of Form B I have tried to set the binding source of Form A `BindingNavigator` control but this has not worked. Code below. Any help appreciated.

```
FormA frm = new FormA();
frm. BindingNavigator.BindingSource = this.FormBDataGridViewBindingSource;
```